# Git is asking me to track my whole user file

Tags: git, terminal

I am just a beginner and just figuring out how to use git and GitHub. While using git status it's saying that my whole "User" directory is untracked and asking me to stage it(I did open a git repo in a remote file inside my user file). I don't know what to do, could someone help me with this.

Comment: Hello, what is your problem, what do you want to do? What mean "I did open a git repo in a remote file inside my user file" - could you explain?

Comment: What's the output of `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`? Is it your user directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if there is a hidden `.git` folder in your User directory

You can do it from the regular file explorer : make  hidden files visible in the folder options, or type `C:\Users\YourUsername\.git`in the navigation bar

from git-bash :

```
# go to your home dir
cd ~
ls -d .git
```

---

If it is present, a git repository was initialized in your home.

It's no big deal, just check if there are commits in this repo that you would want to keep (`git log --oneline --graph` from git bash, or open the explorer in the GUI frontend you use)

If there is nothing worth keeping, simply delete the hidden `.git` folder.

If there *are* some commits to keep, and you need help extracting these, please ask another question.